# which element belongs to the subgroup H

Tags: group-theory

[image]

2 is obvious but 3 I couldn't get by simple multiplication. If 3 was obtainable, then so would be I. The question is I couldn't get 3 but I couldn't argue rigorously that 3 is not obtainable! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For $x,y\in G$, what is the meaning of $(x,y)$? Apparently, this should be $\in G$ again ...

Comment: I guess that means an element generated by (a,b)

Comment: $b^3 = (b^2)^5(b^7)^{-1}$.

Comment: @ Derek, then how to deal with a?

Comment: $a^0$ is the identity element.

Comment: It is still not clear what $(x,y)$ is. The notation suggests $G$ is a direct product of subgroups $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$? The notation is still off as if $a,b\in G$ then you would normally denote $(a^6,b^2)\in G\times G$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming we are discussing the direct product.*

The element $a^0b^3$ is in $H$ if and only if there are integers $r,s$ such that 
$a^0b^3=(a^6b^2)^r(a^4b^7)^s$

We require $6r+4s=0,2r+7b=3$ and so $r=-6/17,s=9/17$. This element is not in $H$.

Comment: this also assumes something about the order of $a$ and $b$

Comment: Yes. The question should be clear about this - lacking such knowledge I've assumed they have infinite order.